# PHP calling recursive function fails

Tags: php, recursion

```
ID         NAME                        PARENT_ID 
1         Sales                             
2         Marketing                      1
3         sales_optimiztaion.txt         2                         
5         list.xls                       6
6         General data                   1
```

I have hierarchial table with data and function which counts how many files contains some specific folder and its subfolders. In this case folder Sales contains two files - list.xls an sales_optimiztaion.txt.
Function:

```
<?
function get_pathS($node) { 

global $countSS;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                       WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
$ro = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($ro['NAME']!='') { 
            $path=$ro['NAME'];

            if($path=='Sales'){
                $countSS++;
                $path=get_path($ro['PARENT_ID']);
        }

    $path=get_pathS($ro['PARENT_ID']);
}
 return $countSS;
```

} ?>

Function works fine, but I want to pass 'Sales' as an argument to the function like this:

```
<?
function get_pathS($node, $manage) { 

global $countSS;
$result = mysql_query('SELECT NAME, PARENT_ID FROM b_disk_object  
                       WHERE ID="'.$node.'";'); 
$ro = mysql_fetch_array($result); 

    if ($ro['NAME']!='') { 
            $path=$ro['NAME'];

            if($path==$manage){
                $countSS++;
                $path=get_path($ro['PARENT_ID']);
        }

    $path=get_pathS($ro['PARENT_ID']);
}
 return $countSS;

} ?>
```

But after calling function like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){

 $check='Sales';
 get_pathS($row['PARENT_ID'], $check);
 .......
```

It does not work. Whats the problem?

Comment: Does it work when you provide a default value for the second parameter? Like: `function get_pathS($node, $manage = null)`

Comment: It works, but returns incorrect count

Comment: I have declared $countSS as global variable, but what is alternative of this, because I have to call this function multiple times and each time it adds result to previous function call result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call this (in function body)

```
$path=get_pathS($ro['PARENT_ID']);
```

you should pass here second argument too. like this

```
$path=get_pathS($ro['PARENT_ID'], $manage);
```

Comment: One more question... I have declared $countSS as global variable, but what is alternative of this, because I have to call this function multiple times and each time it adds result to previous function call result?